# Spark - loading multiple files individually

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark, this is my first code. Please correct me if i am wrong.

I want to load multiple files, one by one - i don't want to refer a folder to process all together. Wanted to process only selected files.

Below is my code(referred Spark docs), it's processing fine for single file, but when ever i process multiple files it's creating a DataFrame for each file. i wanted data to be added to previous DataFrame, so that all records i add (from multiple files) will reside in single Table (mylogs). Is there any method to do this ? I want to call readFileToSchema(...) method for each file individually.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestApp app = new TestApp();
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application")
                .config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();

        String[] afiles = {"/Users/logs/test1.txt","/Users/logs/test2.txt"};
        final List<String> files = Arrays.asList(afiles);

        for (String file : files) {
            app.readFileToSchema(spark, file);
        }
    }

    public void readFileToSchema(SparkSession spark, String filePath) {

        SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();
        JavaRDD<String> logRDD = sc.textFile(filePath, 1).toJavaRDD();

        String schemaString = "a1 b1 c1 d1";

        List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String fieldName : schemaString.split(" ")) {
            StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType, true);
            fields.add(field);
        }
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

        RegexMatch reg = new RegexMatch();
        JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = logRDD
                .filter(line -> reg.isMatched(line))
                .map((Function<String, Row>) line -> {

                    String[] sp = line.split(" ");
                    String msg = line.substring(line.indexOf(sp[5]));
                    return RowFactory.create(sp[0] + " " + sp[1], sp[4], sp[5], msg);
                });

        Dataset<Row> logDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);

        logDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("mylogs");

        Dataset<Row> results = spark.sql("SELECT distinct(b1) FROM mylogs");

        List<Row> allrows = results.collectAsList();

        System.out.println("size : " + allrows.size());

        //spark.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: The method you're looking for would be `unionAll`

Comment: unionAll is deprecated, and more over union comes into play only at the time of Querying ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestApp app = new TestApp();
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application")
            .config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();

        String afiles = "/Users/logs/test1.txt,/Users/logs/test2.txt";
        app.readFileToSchema(spark, afiles);
    }

    public void readFileToSchema(SparkSession spark, String files) {
        SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();
        JavaRDD<String> logRDD = sc.textFile(files).toJavaRDD();

   //Rest of your code.
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually i know this solution, but my issue is different, i don't want to send all files at once, need to invoke readFileToSchema(...) for each file individually as shown in my example( for loop).